# Some Questions About NavMesh

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is NavMesh multi-threaded, can it handle multiple calls at the same time by itself and is it as good as A* Pathfinding Project in the unity assets store?

Unity's official documentation site doesn't provide any info about it and there is no info about it on other sites either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation of the paths is single-threaded and happens on the main thread.

Updating the agents is multi-threaded.

It is supposed to be pretty optimised but it will use time on your main thread.

According to [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-navmesh-pathing-using-all-cores.1035490/) it planned to change that.

How much of an impact that is depends on what kind of project you want to do. If the A* Project you mention is fully multi-threaded it will likely perform better for a large number of agents.